# Need to delete all tables based on their references i.e FK and PK

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I need to create a script to clean up all the objects in the schema 'myschema'.
Order will be like

1. All tables(FK PK order)

How do I achieve this in one PLSQL block.

```
 set serveroutput on;
declare
lv_str varchar2(1000);
begin
for c in(select distinct a.table_name as table_name, b.table_name as parent_table_name
from
all_constraints a
left outer join all_constraints b on a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name and a.owner = b.owner) loop
lv_str :='DROP TABLE '||c.table_name;
--lv_str :='DROP TABLE '||c.parent_table_name;

dbms_output.put_line(lv_str);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Ummmm, you know that there are a whole lot of objects in the `SYSTEM` schema that are created by Oracle and somewhat critical to the database functioning, right?  If you do this, your database will probably be unusable.  Or at least you'll constantly be running into fun, new issues that aren't going to come up on any Google search.

Comment: @Justin Cave Sorry. Actually, I have delete it from my schema and not from SYSTEM.

Comment: @Justin Cave We can use dbms_output instead of 'execute immediate' so that nothing will be permanently deleted. Can you help here how to achieve this

Comment: @JustinCave I have edited the code will this work ?

Comment: Have you tested your code?  Does it work?

Comment: @Justin Cave Yes, I have made the changes and tested accordingly but how to delete parent table as well in the same loop??

Comment: Add that to your question.  Ideally, add a test case (or create one on livesql.oracle.com or dbfiddle and add a link).  If you're only worrying about dropping tables, update your question to remove the reference to "all objects".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237046/discussion-between-albertalex-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a script I use to clear Scott's schema. Why? I use it for testing purposes and, as time goes by, it turns into a mess. I don't pay much attention about what I remove and in which order; I simply run it 2-3 times and everything's gone. See if you can use it, improve it if you want.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   l_user  VARCHAR2 (30) := 'SCOTT';
   l_str   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   IF USER = l_user
   THEN
      FOR cur_r IN (SELECT object_name, object_type
                      FROM user_objects
                     WHERE object_name NOT IN ('EMP',
                                               'DEPT',
                                               'BONUS',
                                               'SALGRADE'))
      LOOP
         BEGIN
            l_str :=
                  'drop '
               || cur_r.object_type
               || ' "'
               || cur_r.object_name
               || '"';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
         EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
               NULL;
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
END;
/

PURGE RECYCLEBIN;

SELECT * FROM user_objects;
```

---

How to drop foreign key constraints first, and then drop tables:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_name, constraint_name
  5                  from user_constraints
  6                  where constraint_type = 'R')
  7    loop
  8      l_str :=  'alter table ' || cur_r.table_name ||
  9                        ' drop constraint '  || cur_r.constraint_name;
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 11
 12      execute immediate l_str;
 13    end loop;
 14
 15    --
 16
 17    for cur_r in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name not in ('EMP', 'DEPT'))
 18    loop
 19      l_str := 'drop table ' || cur_r.table_name;
 20
 21      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 22
 23      execute immediate l_str;
 24    end loop;
 25  end;
 26  /
alter table TDET drop constraint SYS_C00105662
drop table BONUS
drop table SALGRADE
drop table TEST
drop table MYTABLE
drop table TABLEB
drop table TABLEA
drop table EMPLOYEES
drop table T_PRINT
drop table TMAS
drop table TDET

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I need the drop table to be based on the references i.e FK and PK order. How to do that?

Comment: As I said: I run that script 2-3 times, which is usually enough to drop all tables, regardless of foreign key constraints. If you'd want to do it "properly" and drop detail tables first and their masters next, script becomes way more complex because that relationship doesn't have to be 1:1 as many tables may reference some other table which then reference some other tables ... that's a *chain* in which you'd have to find tables that aren't referenced at all and drop them first, etc. I'd say that it would then be **simpler** to drop foreign key constraints first, and then drop tables.

Comment: Yes, I want to drop the tables in order of their references(FK, PK). Can you help me with the query

Comment: Sorry, but no. In my opinion, that's too complex. Drop FK constraint first (that's easy), then drop all tables.

Comment: @Liitlefoot Example please ?

Comment: Sorry, had to go offline. I edited the answer and added an example which shows how to drop FK constraints first, and then drop tables. Have a look, please.